# PHP Pagination Confusion

Tags: php, pagination

I'm not asking for a whole engine of code. I'm working on a blog/magazine website. Here are the **2 styles of paginations**. I see people use these types of addresses:

1. `example.com/browse?page=100`
2. `example.com/page/100/`

I understand 1.'s. But, 2. doesn't give me an impression of php usage in the address.

I did a search on Google, but there are only helps on 1. How do you manage 2.? Because whenever you write a new article, you have to push the content throughout every html? Did they use "fake addresses"? because I tried `example.com/page/100/index.html` and there is no such website.

**Can anyone point me to a webpage or explain to me how did they manage 2. style of pagination? Which has a better UX?**

Sorry if this is a bad title. Please help me edit and ask me if anywhere isn't clear.

Comment: They use URL rewriting for 2 and it's and the URL is just an MVC pattern. browse seems to be default conntroler action and then page is and paginiation parameter info with value 100. so the controller knows he should open the `browse` with parameter 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **URL Rewriting** that is responsible or translating nice-looking Urls to their 'real' path on the server.

In your case,

```
www.example.com/page/100/
```

might be rewritten on the server to something like

```
www.example.com/browse.php?page=100
```

More info:

- [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache
- [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) for IIS